# Why do the Google OAuth 2.0 docs for Web Apps not mention "state" parameter?

Tags: google-oauth

Reading over the Google OAuth docs at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#handlingresponse, I was surprised (or at least curious why) there's no documentation on `state`. It seems pretty important to prevent CSRF attacks (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.4.1.8) even in the non-implicit flow.

Am I missing something that suggests `state` param is not absolutely necessary? Seems like it should be emphasized in the docs so people don't leave their apps with CSRF vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned but only for the HTTP/Rest examples.  Take a look at the redirect section with HTTP/Rest selected.

> Redirecting to Google's OAuth 2.0 server
>
> When your application needs to access a user's data, redirect the user
>   to Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
>
> HTTP/REST
>
> Generate a URL to request access from Google's
>   OAuth 2.0 endpoint at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth.
>   This endpoint is accessible over HTTPS; plain HTTP connections are
>   refused.
>
> The set of query string parameters supported by the Google
>   Authorization Server for web server applications are:
>
> ... Omitted text ...
>
> state - Any string -  Provides any state that might be useful to your
>   application upon receipt of the response. The Google Authorization
>   Server roundtrips this parameter, so your application receives the
>   same value it sent. To mitigate against cross-site request forgery
>   (CSRF), it is strongly recommended to include an anti-forgery token in
>   the state, and confirm it in the response. See OpenID Connect for an
>   example of how to do this.